# How do you create an access method to convert a string to a boolean

Tags: java, arrays, string, methods, boolean

How do you create an access method to convert a string to a boolean?
current access method below

```
protected boolean fullTime;

/**
 * Get the value of fullTime
 *
 * @return the value of fullTime
 */
public boolean isFullTime() {
    return fullTime;
}

/**
 * Set the value of fullTime
 *
 * @param fullTime new value of fullTime
 */
public void setFullTime(boolean fullTime) {
    this.fullTime = fullTime;
}
```

Can it be done similar to this below

```
/**
 * set the coaches names
 * @param coaches as an array of strings
 */
public void setCoaches(String coaches)
{
    this.coaches = getStringAsArray(coaches);
}

public String getCoachesAsString()
{
    return getArrayAsString(coaches);
}
```

Comment: return new Boolean(fullTime).toString(); and Boolean.parseBoolean(yourString);

Comment: @RichKid was it useful?

Comment: Thanks for the response, it worked well. I just require one last adjustment. I want the output to display Full-Time if true and Part-Time if false. I have this so far..   assert Boolean.parseBoolean( "no" ) == false; 
assert Boolean.parseBoolean( "yes" ) == true;

Comment: ^^ @DavidPérezCabrera

Comment: @RichKid edited with the adjustment.

Comment: @DavidPérezCabrera Thanks for your ongoing help. This displays the output "yes" or "no" and i need it to read "Full-Time" or  "Part-Time"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

```
protected boolean fullTime;

public String getFullTimeAsString(){
    return Boolean.toString(fullTime);
}

public void setFullTimeAsString(String fulltimeStr){
    fullTime = "true".equalsIgnoreCase(fulltimeStr);
}
```

EDITED:

```
private static final String YES = "yes";
private static final String NO = "no";
protected boolean fullTime;


public String isFullTimeAsString() {
    return fullTime? YES: NO;
}

public void setFullTime(String fullTime) {
    this.fullTime =YES.equalsIgnoreCase(fullTime);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you wanted?

```
protected boolean fullTime;

public String isFullTimeAsString() {
    return String.valueOf(fullTime);
}

public void setFullTime(String fullTime) {
    this.fullTime = Boolean.parseBoolean(fullTime);
}
```